# EasyAR. Unity. Problem with publishing. Family Policy

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, easyar

EasyAR. Unity. Problem with publishing. Family Policy

Does Unity version of EasyAR send any of this data to server?

SIM Serial
Build Serial
BSSID
MAC
SSID
IMEI and /or IMSI

We don't have any ads in app, we've remove all libraries corresponded to ad, we've removed all analitics, we've removed firebase from project. Specially we do not send any data to remote server. The only reason may be side modules (EasyAR) that we use in project. Is there any way to find out what module is transmitting this information and how we can turn off the transmission of this information

Here`s email from Google

During review, we found that your app violates the Families Policy Requirements. We’ve identified that Your app or an SDK in your app (App Bundle: 12) transmits identifier(s) from children or unknown users that do not comply with our Families Policy. These identifiers may include but are not limited to Build Serial Number.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is Easy Ar, when sending the bundle id to check the license this error is generated.

I fixed it by switching to the free version of vuforia.

Answer (score 0):

we are having the same issue. our game was published before 2 year ago with easy AR all working fine. but google rejectd this app before a month and mail say that.

Apps targeting children should not transmit the following from children or users of unknown age: SIM Serial,Build Serial,BSSID,MAC,SSID,IMEI and /or IMSI.

we are using unity in-app purchase, but many of our other game use unity inapp but that doesn't have any issue. this might because of easy AR. we are using older version of easyar

[Result of Charls proxy see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYJaa.png)